# No route matches get signup_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Hi I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial, currently on chapter 7.  I just added a sign up page but I'm getting the error message:

Edit: added more of the error message
No route matches [GET] "/signup_path"
Rails.root: C:/Sites/sample_app

Here is my routes file

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do 
  resources :users
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',             via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

view file for home-page

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", 'signup_path', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

routes

```
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
root_path   GET /   static_pages#home
signup_path GET /signup(.:format)   users#new
help_path   GET /help(.:format) static_pages#help
about_path  GET /about(.:format)    static_pages#about
contact_path    GET /contact(.:format)  static_pages#contact
```

Comment: In your console, can you do `rake routes` and how us what you get?

Comment: @dmtri.com undefined local variable or method 'routes'

Comment: show us the view. How are you defining your link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Route Helper**

The problem is you're referencing `'signup_path'` as a string:

```
<%= link_to "Signup", 'signup_path' %>
```

The problem here is that when you reference a [route / path helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code), you are calling a *method*. Every helper in Rails is a *method* - meaning if you reference a *string*, the system won't be able to call the method you need.

To fix this, you should [read up about using route / path helpers in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) - and use the helper methods from your routes:

```
<%= link_to "Signup", signup_path %>
```

--

**Routes**

A little bonus for you:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path_names: { new: "signup" }
resources :static_pages, only: [] do
   collection do
      get :help
      get :about
      get :contact
   end
end
```

You'll want to use the [`path_names`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments) argument for your `users` resource in your routes. This will keep your routes much cleaner (DRY)

Comment: Thanks that did the job!  I knew it was something small like that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide a name for your custom route using the option 'as'.

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new', via: 'get', :as => 'signup'
```

You can verify that the named route is setup properly by doing

```
rake routes | grep signup
```

in your console. you should see something like

```
signup GET  /signup(.:format)          users#new
```

In your view you can use it like

```
<%= link_to "Signup", signup_path%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise, try following in your routes, customize as needed

```
devise_for :users, path: "auth", path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

Comment: Michael Hartl's tutorial doesn't use devise unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the

get 'users/new" line in the routes.rb file, as stated in the tutorial.

that line creates a new_users_path helper

right after listing 7.3,  you will see the following:

```
 Listing 7.3: Adding a Users resource to the routes file.
config/routes.rb
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  .
  .
  .
end
You might have noticed that Listing 7.3 removes the line

get "users/new"
```

here is the link
http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#cha-sign_up

**update**

From the comments below, I think you are trying to visit via a browser /signup_path

your entry in the routes.rb file

```
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',             via: 'get'
```

creates a url such as localhost:3000/signup

it does **not** create a url localhost:3000/signup_path

in the tutorial you will see references to signup_path
this is a "helper" method that rails creates which can be used as a shortcut for the url inside of rails.  In the tutorial you will see  tests making use of this such as

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

in this case signup_path is not the url, but a helper method

Comment: as others have said , to a rake routes,  do you see a line like signup GET /signup(.:format)  users#new ?

Comment: well there is this line: signup_path GET /signup(.:format) users#new

Comment: but that's from the error page of http://localhost:3000/signup_path, I can't actually do 'rake routes' in my command line, it returns 'undefined local variable or method 'routes' '

Comment: bundle exec rake routes ?

Comment: you should try to figure out why rake routes does not work ... it is very helpful ... I think it should just be signup, not signup_path ... you should post the full content of your routes.rb ... the tutorial is  great, but it is easy to miss a step

Comment: oh wait ... you can't go to localhost:3000/signup_path ... the tests say vist signup_path, but that is using the helper method that rails creates ... the url would be localhost:3000/signup